# TypeError: globalThis.reportError is not a function

Tags: javascript, promise

I tried to use `self.reportError(e)` but it said that self is not defined (I'm running tests)

I then tried `globalThis.reportError(e)` and now it says "TypeError: globalThis.reportError is not a function"

I'm trying to call the global method `reportError`
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/reportError

Comment: why should it be a function?

Comment: @Bravo trying to call the global method https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/reportError

Comment: Are you sure you're using a browser that [supports](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/reportError#browser_compatibility) this feature?

Comment: @NickParsons as specified in the question I'm running tests, so it's not running in the browser, but I'll check about Node

Comment: I do know about `reportError` - guess I was asking the above ... is it supported in ***your*** browser

Comment: I just realize it is not supported in Node.js, but then what is the alternative to 'throw an error out of the promise chain' ?

Comment: So, this wasn't about a browser at all - the alternative depends on the exact nature of your code - how are you trying to use this

Comment: [this](https://github.com/nodejs/node/issues/38947) may provide some interesting reading for you

Comment: I have a piece of code that is running a set of functions with reduce (like a pipeline of functions building an accumulated value). Some of these functions are async, and when an error happens, the error is being swallowed (despite having try/catch blocks), because that code is quite nested in the codebase, I thought it'd just be easier to break the chain by throwing with reportError. Actually I don't even see how to stop reduce iterating when one of the functions throws, it's quite complex, so reportError seemed the easy way to just throw globally and stop the execution and the promise chain.

Comment: @Bravo you may just add an answer that reportError is not available in NodeJS and I'll accept the answer, and I'll write a new question with actual code. Optionally explain why it's not in NodeJS with following link: https://github.com/nodejs/node/issues/38947

Comment: You can answer your own question if you think others will come across a situation where they think nodejs has a method only available in browsers

Answer (score 1):

Thanks to help provided in the comments, I realized `reportError` is not available for NodeJS, only in browsers.
See also:
https://github.com/nodejs/node/issues/38947